# Strange bug with simple calculator in xcode

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I'm starting to learn ios7, and in my first program(a simple RPN Calculator), and I got this really weird bug. I simply followed the walkthrough from a ios5 course in iTunes U, so this might be the answer to my problem.

When I hit the enter button with the digit on the display, the app collapses. Here is the action that the enter activates.

```
- (IBAction)enterPressed
{
 NSString *value = _display.text;
[self.brain pushOperand:value.doubleValue];
self.isInTheMiddle = NO;
}
```

Brain is my model, and this is the pushOperand method:

```
-(void)pushOperand:(double)operand
{
[self.operandStack addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand]];
}
```

As I started debugging, the breakpoint is in the:

```
[self.operandStack addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand]];
```

And what the console shows is that "unrecognized selector sent to instance [...]".

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I just can't find out any explication to this bug.

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: 2014-01-22 14:58:10.386 Calculator[8683:70b] -[CalculatorViewController enterPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c69540
2014-01-22 14:58:10.406 Calculator[8683:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CalculatorViewController enterPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c69540'

Comment: Where have you set the action to the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your connections inspector for the "enter button". You may get this exception if you have two connections to the "touch up inside" action of your button. Just delete all the connections for "Enter" button and reconnect it to `- (IBAction)enterPressed` again.